# "heroku logs" gives me "Not found"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

On my latest deployment to Heroku with my Rails app, I'm getting an error page when trying to access the webpage.

Nothing spectacular with this, but when I try to look at the logs with the command

`heroku logs`

I get the message

`Not found`

This has never happened to me before. I can restart the app, I can do migrations but not see the logs - any clues what is going on?

Comment: Try doing `heroku logs -a my-heroku-app-name` replacing `my-heroku-app-name` with whatever your heroku app's name is

Comment: Honestly, the only idea I have is that your default app name on the heroku toolbelt doesn't point to any real app

Comment: I have been deploying and using the app regularly the last month (without any problems). Not touched my other apps, nor any heroku configurations. I want to try to specify the app name, but cannot find out the app name....

Comment: That made it! :) 
I had to authenticate, but then it worked.

Comment: Btw, found out the name by logging in to their web interface.
Btw2, if you put your first comment as answer I'll pick it as the accepted one.

Comment: For anyone who sees the same error, but is sure they have the app name set via `-a` or `--app-name` - check that you have run migrations. I hadn't done that, and instead of getting that message, I got the `Not Found` response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing `heroku logs -a my-heroku-app-name` replacing `my-heroku-app-name` with whatever your heroku app's name is. This can be found in the Heroku web interface.